# What are Resident instaces GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Please let me know the difference between the  Resident instances and Dynamic instances.
I am using Modules with automatic scaling.

I did Google it, but didn't find useful info.

please point me to some useful resources regarding this.?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Types_of_Backends

Comment: I'm not using Backends. I'm using Frontends with modules. I set "min-idle-instances" as 5. App engine created 5 resident instances. How these are different from Dynamic instances.